# How do i correct this trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have implemented a trigger on a table which makes sure that table does not contain more than one row with 1 as bit value in one of its column. But the trigger somehow is not working fine.

```
create trigger [dbo].[flyingdutchman_needs_a_captain]
on [dbo].[flyingdutchman]
after insert, update, delete as
begin
set nocount on;
set rowcount 0;
begin try
declare @captainsum int
set @captainsum = 0     
set @captainsum = (select sum(case when uniontable.iscaptain = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
from (
    select iscaptain from dbo.flyingdutchman 
    union all
    select inserted.iscaptain as iscaptain from inserted
    union all
    select deleted.iscaptain as iscaptain from deleted
    ) as uniontable
having sum(case when uniontable.iscaptain = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  <> 1)     
if(@captainsum <> 1)
begin
    throw 50000,'flying dutchman is cursed and needs a captain.',1;
end     
end try
begin catch
if xact_state()<>0
    rollback transaction;
throw;
end catch
end
```

flyingdutchman is a table with three columns:

`SailorId(int),SailorName(varchar),IsCaptain(bit)`

and the following rows:

[image]

When executing the query:

```
insert into dbo.flyingdutchman(Sailorname,IsCaptain)
values('Davy Jones',1)
```

I get the error:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   FLYINGDUTCHMAN_NEEDS_A_CAPTAIN, Line xx FLYING DUTCHMAN IS CURSED AND
>   NEEDS A CAPTAIN.

I expect that this query should run fine and trigger should not get fired.

Comment: It's an `after` trigger, you don't need to check the `inserted` and `deleted` tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an `after` trigger, all the changes are already in the table - you don't need to query the `inserted` and `deleted` tables - that's the reason you get the wrong result.

You can simply do this:

```
if 1 <> (select count(*) from dbo.flyingdutchman where iscaptain = 1)
    throw 50000,'flying dutchman is cursed and needs a captain.',1;
```

However, I suspect you should probably do something like this instead:

```
declare @captainsCount int;
select @captainsCount = count(*) from dbo.flyingdutchman where iscaptain = 1
if @captainsCount = 0 
    throw 50000,'flying dutchman is cursed and needs a captain.',1;
if @captainsCount > 1 
    throw 50000,'flying dutchman has too many captains.',1;
```

Comment: You are right zohar, I do not need to query Iserted/Deleted as this is an after trigger. This is most relevant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Can be simplified to:

```
create trigger [dbo].[flyingdutchman_needs_a_captain]
on [dbo].[flyingdutchman]
after insert, update, delete as
begin
set nocount on;

begin try   

-- prevents multiple captains
IF  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[flyingdutchman] WHERE iscaptain = 1   ) > 1 
    throw 50000,'Too many captains is not good.',1;

-- prevents setting all captains off, if one was already assigned
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[flyingdutchman] WHERE iscaptain = 1   )
   AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE iscaptain = 1   ) 
    throw 50001,'flying dutchman is cursed and needs a captain.',1;


end try
begin catch
if xact_state()<>0
    rollback transaction;
throw;
end catch

end
```

Comment: This solution allows me to add Davy Jones as captain i.e. I was able to insert the row. But I also allows deleting that row lateron, so did'nt work as expected

Comment: @Ravishkumarpatil, point taken, a second check is something was missing

Comment: Yes this solution worked as expected. Now flying dutchman is properly cursed :D
Thanks for the help Alexander.

Answer (score 2):

your trigger always get fire , because your condition `if(@captainsum <> 1)` is always true
when your summary in sub query equals 1 , the `@captainsum` = null  because of your having statement , then your variable  is null or other values except 1

```
create trigger [dbo].[flyingdutchman_needs_a_captain]
on [dbo].[flyingdutchman]
after insert, update, delete as
begin
set nocount on;
set rowcount 0;
begin try
declare @captainsum int
set @captainsum = 0     
set @captainsum = (select sum(case when uniontable.iscaptain = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
from (
    select iscaptain from dbo.flyingdutchman where SailorId not in (select SailorId from inserted)
    union all
    select inserted.iscaptain as iscaptain from inserted
    union all
    select deleted.iscaptain as iscaptain from deleted
    ) as uniontable
having sum(case when uniontable.iscaptain = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  <> 1)     
if(@captainsum <> 1)
begin
    throw 50000,'flying dutchman is cursed and needs a captain.',1;
end     
end try
begin catch
if xact_state()<>0
    rollback transaction;
throw;
end catch
end
```

Comment: If i print @captainsCount, it prints to 2 to my surprise, when I try inserting Davy Jones as captain.

Comment: don't surprise my friend just edit your trigger and add this "SailorId not in (select SailorId from inserted)" after your select from main table

Comment: Thanks for solution masoud, using this solution, the check to insert only one captain worked. However I was able to delete the only captain of the ship. One little correction is required.